# Handle Credentials in CircleCI - Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci, circleci-2.0

The Rails Team introduced a new way to handle secrets in the application using a new concept called credentials (http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/9/23/this-week-in-rails-new-credentials-configuration-bugfixes-and-more/).

To encrypt and decrypt the credentials files you need the `master.key` file. I'm running my test suite using CircleCI but the `master.key` is not available in the github repository and therefore CircleCI can not build the application correctly.

What is the best way to handle this situations in CircleCI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#encrypted-secrets) the key can either be in a key file or an environment variable called `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`

Under settings in CircleCI you can go Build Settings > Environment Variables and place the key there.

Comment: I'm using this solution on Circle 2.0 and it works well for me

Comment: I spent a full day looking for this. Thank you. Rails was silently eating the error around the key not being set.